# How to fill data right to left in Flutter gridview

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview

I am trying to fill Grid view data from right to left, as the application is in arabic and everything is RTL.

Here is what I want
[image]

I am using Stream builder to populate data and the following Gridview widget

```
 Widget productGrid(List<Product> products) => GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        reverse: true,

        controller: _scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 14,
        children: products
            .map(
              (product) => MyBookList(item: product),
            )
            .toList(),
      );
```

Is there any way I can reverse the item filling direction Horizontally , like the `reverse` param made filling vertically bottom to top.
Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use `Directionality` widget

```
Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: productGrid()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works perfectly. Could you please explain how do the text direction works for filling direction of grid